# Trouble with format specifiers and replacement fields in python

Tags: python

I've got a project for school and I completed my code. The purpose of the code is to take a word input by the user (using an infinite while loop to constantly check for input) and then print that word as it is and backwards as well using format specifiers and "[::-1]."

Here's my code:

```
b = 1
while b == 1:
    a = input("Type a word to format. Typing quit will exit the program: ")
    if a == "quit":
        break
        print("Goodbye!")
    else:
        print("{[0]:><20}{[1]:<>20}".format(a, a[::-1]))
```

When I run the code, with the word "monkey" for example, this is what I get:

```
Type a word to format. Typing quit will exit the program: monkey
m>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<e
Type a word to format. Typing quit will exit the program:
```

The results **should** look like this:

```
Type a word to format. Typing quit will exit the program: monkey
monkey>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<yeknom
Type a word to format. Typing quit will exit the program:
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong. Any comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take another look at your format specifiers - why the square brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want square brackets around the replacement fields:

```
>>> a = 'monkey'
>>> print("{0:><20}{1:<>20}".format(a, a[::-1]))
monkey>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<yeknom
```

On more recent versions (python2.7+, python3.2?+), you don't need even need to specify the field number (they're enumerated by default):

```
>>> a = 'monkey'
>>> print("{:><20}{:<>20}".format(a, a[::-1]))
monkey>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<yeknom
```